# Cannot display this video mode optimum resolution 1280x1024 60hz error

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

PC configurations:

- Quad Core
- 4GB RAM
- 160 GB Hard disk
- 256 MB 64bit Raedon x1600 series PCI card
- Dell 1908 FP LCD
- Windows 7 Ultimate

Problem :

Whenever I tried to install whether windows 8 or 8.1, after booting when Windows 8 logo appear just after that I got an error

> cannot display this video mode optimum resolution 1280x1024 60hz

something like that.

Question:

How to get rid of this error ?

After getting that error I restart PC and continues with windows 7. I tried many versions of windows 8.1 but with the same error. But it never appear while installing windows 7 or XP.

As my current Windows 7 screen resolution is 1280*1024 (recommended) and is working perfectly.

Comment: It seems like your hardware doesn't support Windows 8.

Comment: It sounds like it's set for a different resolution than 1280x1024, probably higher, and thus failing.  Reboot, push F8 to get the boot menu, and select either VGA mode or safe and check what the resolution is set to.

Answer (score 1):

The Radeon X1600 generation was released in 2005 and 2006, and is ancient. There have been seven generations of AMD graphics cards since then. There have been no driver updates since 2010 (Catalyst 10.2). AMD does not support Windows 8 with this graphics card.